# RuntimeException after adding google-services to ChatSecure

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am modifying [ChatSecure](https://github.com/guardianproject/ChatSecureAndroid) to have a push notifications feature and I am trying to do that using `GCM` OR `FCM` but once I add `com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0` to the project `build.gradle` file the App crashes.
I tried both of `GCM` and `FCM` but once I add this line the app always crashes :

```
 06-08 03:05:37.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3157): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 06-08 03:05:37.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3157): Process: info.guardianproject.otr.app.im, PID: 3157
 06-08 03:05:37.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3157): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.guardianproject.otr.app.im/info.guardianproject.otr.app.im.app.NewChatActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #50: Error inflating class fragment
 06-08 03:05:37.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3157):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
 06-08 03:05:37.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3157):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
 06-08 03:05:37.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3157):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
 06-08 03:05:37.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3157):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
 06-08 03:05:37.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3157):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 06-08 03:05:37.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3157):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
 06-08 03:05:37.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3157):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
 06-08 03:05:37.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3157):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 06-08 03:05:37.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3157):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 06-08 03:05:37.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3157):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
 06-08 03:05:37.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3157):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
 06-08 03:05:37.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3157):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 06-08 03:05:37.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3157): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #50: Error inflating class fragment
 06-08 03:05:37.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3157):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:714)
 06-08 03:05:37.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3157):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756)
 06-08 03:05:37.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3157):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759)
 06-08 03:05:37.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3157):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759)
 06-08 03:05:37.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3157):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759)
 06-08 03:05:37.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3157):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
 06-08 03:05:37.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3157):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
 06-08 03:05:37.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3157):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
 06-08 03:05:37.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3157):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
 06-08 03:05:37.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3157):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
 06-08 03:05:37.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3157):    at info.guardianproject.otr.app.im.app.NewChatActivity.onCreate(NewChatActivity.java:195)
 06-08 03:05:37.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3157):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
 06-08 03:05:37.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3157):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
 06-08 03:05:37.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3157):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
 06-08 03:05:37.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3157):    ... 11 more
 06-08 03:05:37.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3157): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #50: Must specify unique android:id, android:tag, or have a parent with an id for info.guardianproject.otr.app.im.app.AccountsFragment
 06-08 03:05:37.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3157):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2205)
 06-08 03:05:37.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3157):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:111)
 06-08 03:05:37.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3157):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:278)
 06-08 03:05:37.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3157):    at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
 06-08 03:05:37.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3157):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:78)
 06-08 03:05:37.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3157):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:690)
 06-08 03:05:37.414: E/AndroidRuntime(3157):    ... 24 more
```

My App `Build.gradle` file :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'info.guardianproject.otr.app.im'
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
.....
.....

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile project(':AndroidEmojiInputLibrary')
    compile project(':AndroidPinning')
    compile project(':CacheWordLib')
    compile project(':MemorizingActivity')
    compile project(':SlidingMenuLibrary')
    compile project(':TibetanTextLibrary')
    compile project(':ViewPagerIndicatorLibrary')
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Once I remove the dependencies it works fine but I need to implement the notifications feature, what to do?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by using an old version of `com.google.gms:google-services`.
Maybe it's not the best solution but it works :

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'
```

Comment: Could you try using compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2'  with the latest version of the google-services plugin.